# How to fix behat 'DMore\ChromeDriver\StreamReadException' in behat script

Tags: php, drupal-8, behat

I am executing my behat script and getting the following exception :

**DMore\ChromeDriver\StreamReadException in /vendor/dmore/chrome-mink-driver/src/DevToolsConnection.php**

I am getting the following exception in my local and also in my Acquia pipeline.Strange thing is that this exception does not appears everytime and appears on different step definations each time.

```
@smoke
Feature: Test SEARCH box
  @javascript @api @errors
  Scenario: Test For the SEARCH box                                                                                     
    Given I am on "/"
                                                                                                   # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::visit()
DMore\ChromeDriver\StreamReadException in /<project_folder>/vendor/dmore/chrome-mink-driver/src/DevToolsConnection.php
```

Comment: same exact problem on our system.

Comment: same problem here too.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Still have not found a solution. I have noticed that when I am running  a headless chrome browser and am using the chrome debug tools things like "clicking" a button will cause this error every time.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me . In your code wherever 'socket_timeout' is being used just increase the time

In my configuration file

**local.yml**

```
sessions:
        default:
          chrome:
            # Set the optimal Socket Timeout to avoid client-server connection problems in behat scripts.
            socket_timeout: 60
```